# Using Intl properly in Android React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, polyfills, javascriptcore, react-intl

I'm trying to use number formatter of `Intl`, which works perfectly on iOS and when debugger is attached to either iOS or Android, but only fails on Android without debugger attached due to outdated JSC in Android.

After a bit research I've found two possible solutions:

- Use `Intl` polyfill
- Use custom JSC in Android

I tried `Intl` polyfill first like this after installing `intl` and `react-intl` using yarn:

```
//in my app's index.js
if (!global.Intl) {
    global.Intl = require('intl');
}
```

Though it still says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl`.

Then I gave up and tried to include custom JSC (I've confirmed that custom AAR is referenced correctly) though I still get the same error. No matter what I do I can't get `Intl` to get running on Android without debugger attached.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm on React Native 0.59.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I wanted to delete this question but I can't since there's already another answer.*

---

It had nothing to do with JSC. My build script wasn't updating the APK properly while I thought it was, and I was trying an old bogus APK over and over again. Otherwise, apparently I was doing everything properly as it works now with the new APK.

Answer (score 51):

Small update, as of React Native v0.60+ you can define intl+ version of the lib.

In your `app/build.gradle`:

`def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`

and have it implemented below in your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    if (enableHermes) {
        ...
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a lifesaver as well as the simplest possible solution.

Comment: I saw this solution in other places, but they don't mention this dependencies step. Why?

Comment: @HenriqueBruno for me the dependencies step was already there.  `jscFlavor` already exists, this is just changing the value

Comment: @Simon I am getting semantic error after this.

Comment: **WARNING**
It will increase your app size by around 25 MBs, which was my case, need to figure out some other way around.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this documented somewhere? If so, could you please link to it?

Comment: Instead of 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+' I would use a specific version BECAUSE the latest version of the library is SDK 21+ (in preview currently).
Therefore, I am using `org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:r250230.2.1` to stay on SDK 19

Answer (score 20):

If disabling Hermes is not an option in your app/build.gradle, and you cant use `org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+` then [Intl polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl) can fix the issue:

```
npm install intl
```

in the code:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en'; // or any other locale you need
```

Comment: Can this be done for android only? e.g. 
if (Platform.android) { 
   require('intl').default
}

Comment: /!\ **This lib is outdated** /!\ and the repo has been archived since 2021. Also It has a lot of unresolved bugs which makes it hard to work with

Answer (score 11):

```
npm i intl
```

After that import

```
import "intl";

import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en";
```

And then use `Intl`

For example

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat(
  "en-IN",
  {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "INR",
  })
  .format(
     (travelTimeInformation?.duration.value *
      SURGE_CHARGE_RATE *
      multiplier) /
      100
    )}
```

Comment: This worked in Expo app. Cheers man

Comment: /!\ **This lib is outdated** /!\ and the repo has been archived since 2021. Also It has a lot of unresolved bugs which makes it hard to work with

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **React Native v0.60+**

In `app/build.gradle` if you already has `jscFlavor`

like, `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'`

replace it with, `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`

and implemented in dependencies

```
dependencies {
  if (enableHermes) {
    ...
  } else {
    implementation jscFlavor
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using custom JSC then don't forget to import the international version as [explained in the read me of JSC Android Buildscripts](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#international-variant):

> For React Native version 0.59, replace original artifact id with
>   android-jsc-intl
>
> ```
> dependencies {
> +   // Make sure to put android-jsc at the the first
> +   implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:r241213"
> +
>     compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
>     implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
>     implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
> }
> ```