# Intl polyfills for React Native 0.63 and hermes

Tags: react-native, polyfills, intl, react-native-hermes

I ran into issues when I turned on hermes in my app. Specifically with Intl support, I'm getting this error in Android `ReferenceError: Property 'Intl' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes`.

I've read these posts already

- [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/m3qba2/announcing_react_native_064_with_hermes_on_ios/gqsvn8i?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- [Github comment](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/23#issuecomment-799253902)
- [Another Github comment](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/23#issuecomment-675098624)

But I can't get this to work. Have anyone applied these solutions succesfully or got this to work with another appoach?

React Native 0.63.3

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581430/1253482 for a simple solution using the `intl` package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those who have the same problem. I've posted the same on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/na6igd/intl_polyfills_for_react_native_063_and_hermes/).

I was finally able to get intl to work updating react native from 0.63.3 to 0.64.1 and installing the polyfills from [@formatjs](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/) and import them in index.js in the order shown in the graph

Comment: And something about how to handle dynamic imports in react native: 
https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/52

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. While also mentioned by Saul, importing them in the correct order means that you have to look at the requirements of your required polyfill, and including those imports above the import that you need. In my case that looked like this:
`import "@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-displaynames/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-displaynames/locale-data/en";`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the import order from the graph, we had an error "Property 'Intl' doesn't exist" on iOS devices because we were importing numberformat before pluralrules.