# Indian rupee currency format, React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to format my textinput value like this

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
```

how can I achieve that can anyone please tell me?

Comment: on key input get the data and add `,` with regex simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Int.NumberFormat` JavaScript API to format Indian Rupees values.

for eg-

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3 })

console.log(formatter.format(1)); 
console.log(formatter.format(10)); 

console.log(formatter.format(10000));
console.log(formatter.format(100000));
```

Comment: showing error ` ReferenceError: Property 'Intl' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes`

Comment: I think `Intl` javascript api is not supported in react-native. you can use polyfills https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496051/intl-polyfills-for-react-native-0-63-and-hermes