# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl (Android Expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, intl

I'm developing React Native app with Expo.
I'm having problems with my app in Android because always send me same error Message:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl`

Reading many post, but I'm still with the same problem

```
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"expo": "^45.0.6",
"native-base": "^3.4.15",
```

Here's my **/android/app/build.gradle**

```js
 def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'

 if (enableHermes) {
     ...
 } else {
     implementation jscFlavor
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution, if `enableHermes` is true.

[If disabling Hermes is not an option in your app/build.gradle, and you cant use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581430/15349624)

Comment: It could be an option but I have about 30 languages in my app. I had to add every single import? because I had them when I init i18n. Maybe there's another way to do NumberFormat without Intl? or using i18nNext?

Answer (score 0):

## ***EDIT***:

*I noticed that `jsc-android-buildscripts` is supported by **Expo** and you might not need to install it if you are using expo. I uninstall it and it worked. Sorry it might not be the answer but I will leave it to others who might have the same problem as me*

Do you have [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts) installed? I want to use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) and I got the same error as you and then noticed that they recommended using  [jsc-android-buildscripts](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/install?id=react-native)

My problem was that in my `/android/app/build.gradle` `jscFlavor` was set to `'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'`

Comment: Thanks @Adam I've tried to config `jsc-android-buildscript` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install Intl:

```
expo install intl
```

and then add imports in your file where you use intl:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```